# Firebase storage upload stopped working on react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-camera, react-native-fetch-blob

I am using

```
"firebase": "^3.6.0",
"react": "15.3.2",
"react-native": "0.37.0",
"react-native-camera": "git+https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^3.0.0",
"react-native-video": "^0.9.0"
```

And i'm trying to upload a video recorded with react-native-video to firebase - this worked but suddenly it stopped working and now it doesn't succeed.

I'm using the following code where this.props.file.path looks something like this:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/vidid.mp4

```
  accept = () => {
    let rnfbURI = RNFetchBlob.wrap(this.props.file.path)
    Blob
    .build(rnfbURI, { type : 'video/mp4;'})
    .then((blob) => {
      // upload image using Firebase SDK
      firebase.storage()
        .ref()
        .child('testImageName')
        .put(blob, { contentType : 'video/mp4' })
        .then((snapshot) => {
          console.log(snapshot)
          blob.close()
          done()
        })
    })
}
```

I tried writing Firebase support, but then won't help me since this is a workaround.

My blob object looks like this:

```
 { listeners: {},
   isRNFetchBlobPolyfill: true,
   multipartBoundary: null,
   _ref: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/VID_20161113_142100.mp4',
   _blobCreated: true,
   _closed: false,
   cacheName: 'blob-559cd5c4-e880-4742-a3fe-dfae7e1a0df0',
   type: 'video/mp4;',
   size: '3665375' }
```

Comment: lets wait for author's response: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/179

Comment: Were you getting a storage/retry-limit-exceeded error?